# Minted line numbers outside frame and outside margin

Tags: minted, alignment, sourcecode

I have a code snippet where I use minted for nice display:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minted}[
        frame=single,
        obeytabs=true,
        tabsize=4,
        linenos,
        numbersep=6pt
    ]{json}
    {  
        "employee": {  
            "name": "test",   
            "salary": 56000,   
            "married": true  
        }  
    }  
    \end{minted}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

However, I can't get the line numbers to be inside the frame. 
This seems to be a common problem and was discussed before, but other solution suggested to use `xleftmargin=\parindent,` which did not help. 
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your post, I understood that you need to print the `line numbers` inside the `frame`, if my assumption is correct, then please try with the below mentioned `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minted}[
        frame=single,
        obeytabs=true,
        tabsize=4,
        linenos,
        numbersep=-10pt
    ]{json}
    {  
        "employee": {  
            "name": "test",   
            "salary": 56000,   
            "married": true  
        }  
    }  
    \end{minted}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Please excuse me, if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks!